How to fix tall headers in Data Table child component
I created a data-table child component that I reuse throughout my org. I followed Rahul Gawale's tutorial on how to have header wrapping (link here)
It worked really well, and now my header's do not wrap. However, now the headers are very tall:

I've tried various things within my CSS to fix this, but I can't seem to find a solution. Changing the height values within the CSS doesn't have any effect at all. What I'd like to achieve is for the header height to be dynamic to what the text is, if that makes sense.
.wrapped-header-datatable .slds-table .slds-th__action .slds-truncate{
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: unset;
    white-space: pre-line;
    /*  uncomment this if you want break the words further */
    /* word-wrap: break-word;*/
}

.wrapped-header-datatable .slds-table .slds-th__action {
    height: 5rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(206 206 206);
}

.wrapped-header-datatable .slds-table .slds-line-height_reset{
    height: 3rem;
}

.slds-table thead th {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

